# Custom MySQL Ordering

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that needs a custom sorting, trimmed down to the bare minimums something like:

```
SELECT u.*, p.*, p.id as product_id
FROM users u, products p 
WHERE u.id = p.user_id
ORDER BY product_id DESC
```

And I get returned a set of rows like:

```
UserID        ProductID
     2                5
     2                4
     3                3
     1                2
     1                1
```

But I want it to actually sort SOMETHING like this (so no 2 UserIDs are adjacent to eachother):

```
 UserID        ProductID
     1                2
     2                4
     3                3
     2                5
     1                1
```

Is this even possible with MySQL, or do I need some PHP magic?

Comment: How would you sort [1,2] if they can't be adjacent? Is [1,3,5] a valid sort order, or is [1,5,3] required?

Comment: this needs some logic. even mysql's `FIELD()` will not help.

Comment: What I meant was, [1,1,2,2,3] is a bad sorting for the UserIDs, I need the UserId's adjacent to eachother to be different numbers, it's okay if it's 2 to 1 or 3 to 2, just not 1 to 1 or 2 to 2.

Comment: @AdamSkiba Just out of curiosity what is the rationale behind this?

Comment: So basically definitively unsorted

Comment: @peterm It's for a site that lists musical tracks for different artists and he does not want the same artist's tracks to be adjacent in the order.

Comment: @AdamSkiba - Tables represent unordered sets of rows. Thus, "adjacent" does not have meaning in SQL.

Comment: @AdamSkiba - Would a random order suffice?

Comment: Would be a waste of time and resources to make a SQL query for that if even possible which I doubt (considering that you may have a weight of a given user id at some point which would not allow u to do this), so retrieve the data and work it out with your php magical code.

Comment: I must agree with Prix, you could _approximate_ it with a not too horrible SQL query, but to solve it completely I can see the PHP solution being _way_ less complex.

Comment: Alright guys, I am gonna have to agree too, with PHP being the solution. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

A canonical way of solving this problem is by enumerating the duplicate rows and then ordering by that value:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT u.*, p.*, p.id as product_id,
             row_number() over (partition by u.id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      FROM users u join
           products p 
           on u.id = p.user_id
     ) t
order by seqnum, id;
```

This will work, as long as no one user has a really long sequence (as in your example).

There is no "always-works" solution, because it is easy to come up with a situation where your goal is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here fetch your sorted results into an array. Then do something like this.

```
 $records = $res->fetchAll();
 $count = count($records);
 $records = array_chunk($records, ceil(count($records)/2);
 $unsorted = array();
 for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++){
      $unsorted[] = $records[$x%2][floor($x/2)];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
CREATE TABLE sortable(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,player_id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO sortable(player_id) VALUES (1),(1),(2),(3),(4),(3),(3),(2),(1),(2),(4),(4);

SELECT * FROM sortable;
+----+-----------+
| id | player_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         1 |
|  3 |         2 |
|  4 |         3 |
|  5 |         4 |
|  6 |         3 |
|  7 |         3 |
|  8 |         2 |
|  9 |         1 |
| 10 |         2 |
| 11 |         4 |
| 12 |         4 |
+----+-----------+

SELECT x.*,COUNT(*) rank FROM sortable x JOIn sortable y ON y.player_id = x.player_id AND y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id ORDER BY player_id,rank;
+----+-----------+------+
| id | player_id | rank |
+----+-----------+------+
|  1 |         1 |    1 |
|  2 |         1 |    2 |
|  9 |         1 |    3 |
|  3 |         2 |    1 |
|  8 |         2 |    2 |
| 10 |         2 |    3 |
|  4 |         3 |    1 |
|  6 |         3 |    2 |
|  7 |         3 |    3 |
|  5 |         4 |    1 |
| 11 |         4 |    2 |
| 12 |         4 |    3 |
+----+-----------+------+

SELECT x.*,COUNT(*) rank FROM sortable x JOIn sortable y ON y.player_id = x.player_id AND y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id ORDER BY rank;
+----+-----------+------+
| id | player_id | rank |
+----+-----------+------+
|  1 |         1 |    1 |
|  3 |         2 |    1 |
|  4 |         3 |    1 |
|  5 |         4 |    1 |
|  2 |         1 |    2 |
|  8 |         2 |    2 |
|  6 |         3 |    2 |
| 11 |         4 |    2 |
|  9 |         1 |    3 |
| 10 |         2 |    3 |
|  7 |         3 |    3 |
| 12 |         4 |    3 |
+----+-----------+------+
```

Answer (score -1):

So if your problem is just that you dont want two records with same id should not come next to each other wha I can think simplest is use

```
 SELECT u.*, p.*, p.id as product_id
FROM users u, products p 
WHERE u.id = p.user_id
ORDER BY user_id%2 DESC
```

Or you can even use other number than 2 to meet any certain order you want....

Comment: I might be missing something, but how does sorting on something derived from the product ID have anything but a randomising effect on the user ID ordering, and thus prevent adjacent equal values?